# What does it mean when someone writes a word in upper case while typing?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, capitalization

An American wrote this to me:

> The runup was completely insane and obvious (and scary). I was in the financial industry at the time, and everyone was figuring out how to protect themselves WHEN. It was all about risk management.

I am not getting the meaning of *WHEN* in it.

Comment: It's a (rather clumsy, and non-standard) way of indicating *emphasis* (normally done with italics, as there). The writer just wants to emphasise the single word because he cant be bothered to flesh the whole sense (i.e. - *when* whatever he's talking about actually happens).

Comment: It means they are yelling at you.

Answer (score 1):

USING ALL CAPS IN TEXT IS—sorry, is the microphone working now? Using all caps in text is a common convention indicating that the writer should be envisioned as shouting, or speaking in a louder than normal voice. As such, the connotation is slightly different from that of *italics* and **boldface**, which indicate emphasis but are not necessarily intended to recall spoken language. This use of all caps was popularized by users of online forums, where written language is often used to approximate verbal conversations. Conventions such as ALL CAPS make it possible to provide tonal cues that would not otherwise be possible. Other such conventions include:

- writing out discourse particles like *uh* and *y'know* to suggest that the writer is, y'know, waffling or being tentative
- writing out "stage directions" for oneself in brackets or parentheses, or by pretending to use the IRC `/me` command: "(/me runs away laughing diabolically)"
- using strikethrough to humorously suggest that the writer accidentally wrote something he regrets and wants to take back, perhaps because <s>his readers are idiots</s> he wants to avoid being insulting. (Sometimes old fogies^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^Hveteran Internet users will even use "[^H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%5EH#.5EH)" to suggest backspacing over text, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> being the ASCII key combination for backspace from the teletype days.)

Some people use all caps in cases where bold or italics might be more appropriate. This usage may be more common among older people who learned to type on typewriters, which did not provide options for bold or italic text. Underlining is also occasionally used in a similar way.